# Delete the BLOB column values

Tags: oracle, blob

I have a table with BLOB column. The segment related to it is huge and all i want is somehow get rid of it. Can you please suggest a best way possible (in terms of time and space) to eliminate all the data in segment without dropping the column. I was thinking of dropping the column and then adding it but it is not the case as the developer is concerned with the position on which the column appears.

Comment: The position in which a column appears should under no circumstance be a problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried to explain too, but the developer is very particular about the column order, so can't help. Otherwise dropping and then adding the blob column was the superfast way.

Comment: Here is not the problem to set BLOB to null or EMPTY_BLOB(), but to reclaim the space used from lobs. You can use CTAS or "alter table ... shrink space" or "ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY LOB (<lob_column>) (SHRINK SPACE)". Just search for "Reclaiming Unused LOB Space".